# Module test path not found

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage, github-actions, coverlet

I'm trying to configure [a GitHub action](https://github.com/IgorBuchelnikov/ObservableComputations/blob/master/.github/workflows/dotnet.yml):

My action contains the job for running the unit test by collecting code coverage. As I see in [the log](https://github.com/IgorBuchelnikov/ObservableComputations/runs/1669587143?check_suite_focus=true):

```
Test Run Successful.
Total tests: 336
     Passed: 336
 Total time: 14.0930 Seconds

Calculating coverage result...
  Generating report 'TestResults/coverage.netcoreapp2.1.info'
```

Nonetheless, after these lines log contains an error message:

```
  /home/runner/.nuget/packages/coverlet.msbuild/2.9.0/build/coverlet.msbuild.targets(31,5): error : Module test path not found [/home/runner/work/ObservableComputations/ObservableComputations/src/ObservableComputations.Test/ObservableComputations.Test.csproj]
```

The job is failed.

I tried to run

```
dotnet test --no-build --filter Name~Casting --verbosity normal /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutput=TestResults/ /p:CoverletOutputFormat=lcov
```

at my local machine (MS Windows) and didn't get this error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason was in -no-build parameter for *dotnet test*. It seems coverage collecting requires *dotnet test* to build itself.

Comment: I get this error intermittently and also have --no-build.  It's odd to me that it works most of the time, but not sometimes.  Was it always not working for you?

Comment: When -no-build parameter is applied I always get this error when building in the GitHub action. When I removed the parameter I never saw this error again. In the MS Windows environment, I always have successful builds regardless of applying the parameter.